# struct pointers in c doesn't return correct value

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#niclude ......

struct sort {
    char  * array;
    int left,right;
};

void quicksortthread(struct sort *s){
    int left, right;
    int i, j, x, tmp;
    pthread_t *th1, *th2;
    char * v;
    struct sort s1;
    struct sort s2;

    left = s->left;
    right = s->right;

    v = s->array;

    printf("\n\n\n\n QT: l=%i, r=%i \n",left,right);

    //sorting algorithm
    if (left >= right)
        return;
    x = v[left];
    i = left - 1;
    j = right + 1;
    while (i < j) {
        while (v[--j] > x);
        while (v[++i] < x);
        if (i < j) {
            char temp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    s1.array = v;
    s1.left = left;
    s1.right = j;
    s2.array = v;
    s2.left = j+1;
    s2.right = right;
    printf("1)left = %i; right= %i\n", left,j);
    printf("2)left = %i; right= %i\n", j+1,right);
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, quicksortthread,&s1);
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, quicksortthread,&s2);
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv){

    pthread_t *th1;
    int fd, len, pg, i, j;
    int left, right;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    char c, *paddr;
    struct sort s;

    /*..LOTS OF THIGS

      Define right and left as integers and
      paddr as a char *

      ..*/

    if(   (right)   >=  (atoi(argv[2]))  ){

        //printf("filling structure\n");
        s.array = paddr;
        s.left = left;
        s.right = right;
        //printf("creating threads\n");
        pthread_create(&th1, NULL, quicksortthread,&s);
    }

    sleep(100);
}
```

After two thread calls it stops working. It is because the structure passed in the function `pthread_create` as a last parameter, seems like incorrect. It compiles and it execute without (for e.g.) segmentation fault. I am sure that I am using in the correct way structures and pointers.

Then the program returns in this way:

```
left = 0; right= 2048
QT: l=0, r=2048 
1)left = 0; right= 0
2)left = 1; right= 2048    

left = 0; right= 0
QT: l=0, r=0 

left = 1037061890; right= 32542
QT: l=1037061890, r=32542
```

**SOLVED:** Ok I have solve this problem changing the thread routine in this way:

```
nt left, right;
int i, j, x, tmp;
pthread_t th1, th2;
char * v;
struct sort * s1;
s1= malloc(sizeof(struct sort *));
struct sort * s2;
s2= malloc(sizeof(struct sort *));

left =  s->left;
right = s->right;
printf("\n\n\n\nleft = %i; right= %i\n", left,right);
v =  s->array;
printf("QT: l=%i, r=%i \n",left,right);

if (left >= right)
return;
x = v[left];
i = left - 1;
j = right + 1;
while (i < j) {
while (v[--j] > x);
while (v[++i] < x);
if (i < j) {

   char temp = v[i];
   v[i] = v[j];
   v[j] = temp;
     }
 }

 s1->array = v;
 s1->left = left;
 s1->right = j;
 s2->array = v;
 s2->left = j+1;
 s2->right = right;
 printf("1)left = %i; right= %i\n", left,j);
 printf("2)left = %i; right= %i\n", j+1,right);
 pthread_create(&th1, NULL, quicksortthread,s1);
 pthread_create(&th2, NULL, quicksortthread,s2);
```

Comment: C or C++? They're not the same language.

Comment: This looks wrong `i = left - 1;
    j = right + 1;
    while (i < j) {`  should it be `while (i+1 < j-1)`?

Comment: `pthread_t *th1;` ==> `pthread_t th1;`

Comment: Sorry! Is in C...

Comment: Why do you cast expresions that are already the correct type? `left = (int) s->left` should just be `left = s->left`.

Comment: `s1= malloc(sizeof(struct sort *));` Might be a bit too small...

Answer (score 0):

`struct sort s` is an automatic variable and you are passing it's pointer to the thread. This is not a good practice. The thread will have it's existence even after the function which called `pthread_create` has returned in which case, the stack variable will be out of scope. Same issue exists for the way you creating threads from `quicksortthread` function itself in which `struct sort s1` and `struct sort s2` are local variables to the quicksortthread function. Better to allocate memory to these structures dynamically.

Also, it is not clear why you have added a `sleep(100)` in your main. You should be using `pthread_join` to wait for the created thread to complete before you exit from main.

`pthread_create` expects only a `pthread_t *` as the first argument, but, you are passing a `pthread**`. `pthread_t *th1` should be `pthread_t th1`.

Comment: I guess the sleep is intended to keep the local variable alive while the thread runs.

Comment: Thanks for answare. I am using sleep function because i am only in a prototype progam phase. So, how can i pass these three values (char *array, int left, int right) to my threads?

Comment: But, quicksortthread itself creates more threads and that function seems to exit after creating those threads.

Comment: Please allocate memory dynamically for the struct sort variables i.e. make it as "struct sort *s1 = malloc(sizeof(struct sort));

Comment: The C standard does not have a concept of "stack" and an implementation is not required to use a stack for such variables. It is an automatic variable, how it is allocated is an implementation detail which is completely irrelevant here. Relevant is the life-time, resp. storage-duration.

Comment: @Olaf, I have changed the wording in my answer a little to suit your comment. But, I think the core of my answer does address the questioner's problem. The way he was using those variables were clearly wrong.